# Get current job Role in Python shell Job - Aws Glue

Tags: python, aws-glue

How can I get the Role ARN for the current job in runtime?

I tried:

```
from awsglue.job import Job
```

to get job info, but since this is a Python shell job I got a `ModuleNotFoundError` message.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding the awsglue.job works only in a spark environment as in requires the gluecontext to be specified. If the goal is to just get the Role ARN I suppose boto3 can also do the trick:

`import boto3
glue = boto3.client('glue')
response = glue.get_job(JobName='somejobname')
response['Job']['Role']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use sts get_caller_identity api to get the Role ARN for the current Python Shell job

```py
import boto3
print(boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Arn'))
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity